# Object manipulation to form new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to create a new object structure from an existing object.

**Currently the data set looks like this:**

```
const jsonStructure = {
    "a11/a22/animations": "snimations",
    "a11/a22/colours": "sl/colours",
    "a11/a22/fonts": "sbal/fonts",
    "a11/a22/visibility": "sisibility",
    "a11/b22/logo": "sages/logo",
    "a11/c22/define": "sst/define",
    "a11/c22/ordered": "st/ordered",
    "a11/c22/unordered": "sunordered",
    "a11/d22/foot": "smeta/foot",
    "a11/d22/head": "smeta/head",
    "a11/e22/blockquote": "slockquote",
    "a11/e22/headings": "s/headings",
    "a11/e22/hr": "ss/e/hr",
    "a11/e22/inline-elements": "s-elements",
    "a11/e22/paragraph": "sparagraph",
    "a11/e22/preformatted": "sformatted",
    "a11/e22/time": "stext/time",
    "b11/f22/menu": "smenu/menu",
    "b11/g22/product-item": "sduct-item",
    "b11/h22/search": "sch/search",
    "b11/i22/sub-menu": "s/sub-menu",
    "c11/j22/footer": "ser/footer",
    "c11/j22/title": "ster/title",
    "c11/k22/header": "ser/header"
};
```

**What i want to achieve is a data structure:**

```
{
  "a11": {
    "a22": {
      "animations": {
        "value": "snimations"
      },
      "colours": {
        "value": "sl/colours"
      }
    },
    "b22": {
      "logo":{
        "value": "sbal/fonts"
      }
    }
    "c22": {
      "define":{
        "value": "sst/define"
      },
      "ordered":{
        "value": "st/ordered"
      }
    }
  },
  "b11": {
    "f22": {
      "menu": {
        "value": "smenu/menu"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

The problem is the way i am structuring the code seems to be wrong, or could be written in a much better fashion. Either way, i keep failing at adding in the segmentation and creation of the object.

```
const structure = {
    a: {},
    b: {},
    c: {}
};

let a11 = [];
let b11 = [];
let c11 = [];

for (var hbp in jsonStructure) {
    if (hbp.includes("a11")) {

    }
    if (hbp.includes("b11")) {

    }
    if (hbp.includes("c11")) {

    }
}
```

Comment: that code doesn't actually do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function for spliting the path to the value and generate new objects for it.

```js
var input = { "a11/a22/animations": "snimations", "a11/a22/colours": "sl/colours", "a11/a22/fonts": "sbal/fonts", "a11/a22/visibility": "sisibility", "a11/b22/logo": "sages/logo", "a11/c22/define": "sst/define", "a11/c22/ordered": "st/ordered", "a11/c22/unordered": "sunordered", "a11/d22/foot": "smeta/foot", "a11/d22/head": "smeta/head", "a11/e22/blockquote": "slockquote", "a11/e22/headings": "s/headings", "a11/e22/hr": "ss/e/hr", "a11/e22/inline-elements": "s-elements", "a11/e22/paragraph": "sparagraph", "a11/e22/preformatted": "sformatted", "a11/e22/time": "stext/time", "b11/f22/menu": "smenu/menu", "b11/g22/product-item": "sduct-item", "b11/h22/search": "sch/search", "b11/i22/sub-menu": "s/sub-menu", "c11/j22/footer": "ser/footer", "c11/j22/title": "ster/title", "c11/k22/header": "ser/header" },
    output = {};

Object
    .entries(input)
    .forEach(([k, v]) =>
        k.split('/').reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, output).value = v);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.split` to get all the paths and build up the nested object:

```
 const result = {};

 for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(jsonStructure)) {
   let acc = result;
   for(const path of key.split("/"))
     acc = (acc[path] || (acc[path] = {}));
   acc.value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `entries` of the input object, using a nested `reduce` to identify (and create, if necessary) the nested object in the accumulator, and then assign to its `value` property:

```js
const jsonStructure={"a11/a22/animations":"snimations","a11/a22/colours":"sl/colours","a11/a22/fonts":"sbal/fonts","a11/a22/visibility":"sisibility","a11/b22/logo":"sages/logo","a11/c22/define":"sst/define","a11/c22/ordered":"st/ordered","a11/c22/unordered":"sunordered","a11/d22/foot":"smeta/foot","a11/d22/head":"smeta/head","a11/e22/blockquote":"slockquote","a11/e22/headings":"s/headings","a11/e22/hr":"ss/e/hr","a11/e22/inline-elements":"s-elements","a11/e22/paragraph":"sparagraph","a11/e22/preformatted":"sformatted","a11/e22/time":"stext/time","b11/f22/menu":"smenu/menu","b11/g22/product-item":"sduct-item","b11/h22/search":"sch/search","b11/i22/sub-menu":"s/sub-menu","c11/j22/footer":"ser/footer","c11/j22/title":"ster/title","c11/k22/header":"ser/header"}

const output = Object.entries(jsonStructure).reduce((a, [keysStr, val]) => {
  const keys = keysStr.split('/');
  const finalObj = keys.reduce((nestedObj, key) => {
    if (!nestedObj[key]) nestedObj[key] = {};
    return nestedObj[key];
  }, a);
  finalObj.value = val;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are great and give you solutions without needing an external package. However, it may be worth bringing to your attention the [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) package on npm which can be used to unflatten an object.
You will need to set the delimiter to '/' in your case like so:

```
var unflatten = require('flat').unflatten


unflatten(yourObject, { delimiter: '/' })
```